# Implicit conversion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting always this strange error when i tray to insert something in my db I thnik it should work and the order should be also right

My query

```
INSERT INTO [123].HolidayTracker.dbo.HtVacationDay
    ( Title, 
      FromDate, 
      UserId,
      ToDate )
SELECT 
      old.[userNote] AS Title,
      newUser.UserId,
      DATEADD(HOUR, 8, old.[holidayDate]) as FromDate,
      DATEADD(HOUR, 8, 
          DATEADD(SECOND, old.[hours] * 3600, old.[holidayDate])) as ToDate
  FROM [HolidayTracker].[dbo].[UserHoliday] old
  INNER JOIN 
      [HolidayTracker].[dbo].HTUser oldUser 
      ON old.htUser_htUserId = oldUser.htUserId
  INNER JOIN 
      [ch-s-0008180].[HolidayTracker].[dbo].HtUser newUser 
      ON oldUser.email = newUser.email
```

Error Message

> Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Implicit conversion from data type
>   datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this
>   query.

Thanks for help and fast answer

Comment: Your insert columns are ordered (Title, FromDate, UserId, ToDate) and select columns are (Title, UserID, FromDate, ToDate). Not the same, just change the order of columns in either part.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Hvala but now there is new error String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: Now that's about your data. Perhaps your old.[userNote] column is longer than your new Title column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [123].HolidayTracker.dbo.HtVacationDay(Title,UserId,FromDate,ToDate)
....
```

You have the insertion fields as

```
(Title,FromDate,UserId,ToDate)
```

and the data as

```
old.[userNote],
,newUser.UserId
,DATEADD....
,DATEADD....
```

The error is that the 3rd expression (datetime) in the SELECT is being forced into the UserId (int) column.

---

> but now I get this new error String or binary data would be truncated.

For that you need to shorten `old.[userNote]` to match the maximum size of the `HtVacationDay.Title` column, e.g.

```
 LEFT(old.userNote, 10)
```

Comment: but now I get this new error String or binary data would be truncated.

Comment: @Mingebag maybe the `usernote` datatype is "longer" than the one of `Title`.

Comment: @Mingebag You use VARCHAR(8000) for the column HtVacationDay.Title?

Answer (score 0):

I think the order of Insert statement and select statement is not right,

You should have

> SELECT old.[userNote] AS Title,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, old.[holidayDate]) as
>   FromDate
>         ,newUser.UserId,DATEADD(HOUR, 8, DATEADD(SECOND, old.[hours] * 3600, old.[holidayDate])) as ToDate
>
> FROM [HolidayTracker].[dbo].[UserHoliday] old ....

OR

You can change the insert statement as

> INSERT INTO [123].HolidayTracker.dbo.HtVacationDay
>       ( Title, 
>         UserId,
>         FromDate, 
>         ToDate )

Thanks